# Does No VOC Polyurethane Work Well?

Tags: wooden-furniture, polyurethane

I am finishing a piece of furniture for my home and would like to use a no (or low) [VOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_organic_compound) (Volatile Organic Compound) product.  However, there does not seem to be many on the  market.  I found one so far:

http://www.vermontnaturalcoatings.com

Have you found a No/Low VOC that works well?  What tips do you have?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of low VOC finishes on the market.Two are [Safecoat Polyureseal BP](http://www.thenaturalabode.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=932&Category_Code=liquids&Store_Code=TNA) and [Minwax Polycrylic](http://www.lowes.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&cId=SEARCH&productId=3078233&cm_mmc=SCE_gps-_-gps-_-gps-_-Minwax%201/2%20Pint%20Polycrylic%20Protective%20Finish%20Gloss%2025555000).

They have one problem. If you have a dark finish, they tend to collect in corners and appear white against the dark stain when they dry.